# PHP base64 encoded image not displaying correctly

Tags: php

I'm trying to send an image (any size) over to an API I'm creating, using base64 encoding. The encoded string hits my API as a parameter in the URL. The API built with PHP.

Once the request hits my API, I want to store the image onto my server, and save the file name in the database.  This is working, however I'm getting some odd outputs with the actual image.

For reference, I also followed http://blog.justin.kelly.org.au/simple-base64-encodedecode-url-safe-functions/ but have the same results.

The image I am trying to store on my server:

[image]

```
$encode = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

echo $encode;
```

For testing, the ouput of this is the string I'm using to pass to my API.

In the API:

```
$image = base64_decode($_POST['image']));
$image_name = md5($image) . ".jpg";
file_put_contents(/public/image/ . $image_name, $image);
```

This works, my image is put onto the server in the correct directory with a random name which is saved to the database.

However, when navigating to the image directly, the image is warped:

[image]

If you have a sharp eye, the top part of the image is actually correct before it starts to fail, which makes me start to think whether the string is not getting encoded correctly to be sent as a parameter?

Any clues would be lovely, cheers.

EDIT: Changed it to POST, removed urlencode/decode & removed `strtr`.

Comment: PHP is truncating your variables. There is a configuration you can change to allow a longer length. I would switch to POST right away.

Comment: also note some browsers/servers put a max limit on url lengths as well

Comment: ...and if you don't use GET, you don't have to urldecode, which is really just another way your code could break

Comment: After you switch to POST if you still have issues, take a look at values of PHP configuration for `post_max_size` and `memory_limit`

Comment: @SetSailMedia: not PHP. the webserver. PHP couldn't really care how long a query paramter is, but the webserver will.

Comment: PHP also sets a limit on max post size, so you'll want to check both the webserver and PHP.  The memory limit is a big one, especially if your code does not empty long strings after using them.  You may want to try replacing the + signs with &#43 instead.

Comment: Okay it seems making it POST helps, however with huge images it gets cut off half way down - but the image isn't scrambled now I guess :) Will have a look into the max post size.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments:

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents($image_path));
```

No `urlencode` or `strtr` needed.  Use POST request, and alter the `post_max_size` on the web server to allow for bigger images to be passed through.

```
$image = base64_decode($this->getParameters('avatar'));
$image_name = md5($image) . ".jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm looking at it wrong, but first you encode it base64 -> urlencode and then you decode it base64 -> urldecode again, shouldn't the latter be in reverse order?

Comment: I’d rather say urldecode should not be applied at all, since PHP does that automatically before populating $_GET.